# Как преобразовать из List<string> в IEqualityComparer<string>

Tags: c#, list

Получаю из строки совпадения в регулярке

```
var lst2 =
Regex.Matches(data.ToString(), "(?<=class=\"row list-item)[\\W\\w]*?class=\"date")
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(x => Regex.Match(x.Value, "(?<=a href=\").+?(?=\")").Value)
.ToList();
```

Также у меня есть `Dictionary<string, List<string>()`

```
 var lst1 = dic[dic.Keys.ElementAt(index)];
```

Хочу убрать одинаковые элементы

```
 var rez = lst1.Distinct(ls2)
```

и у меня выдает ошибку

```
Ошибка  CS1503  Аргумент 2: не удается преобразовать из "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `Distinct` делает не то, что вы думаете, он убирает дубликаты из *одного* множества. (А компаратор ему нужен для того, чтобы понять, какие элементы равны.)

Если вы хотите удалить из `lst1` элементы `lst2`, попробуйте `lst1.Except(lst2)`.